# Why do I need getters and setters in ICommand?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, icommand, relaycommand

New to C#/MVVM and this doesn't make sense to me?

This is my implementation of a RelayCommand inheriting from ICommand:

```
internal class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    private readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute;
    private readonly Action _execute;
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged = (sender, e) => {};

    public RelayCommand(Action execute) : this(execute, null){ }
    public RelayCommand(Action execute, Predicate<object> canExecute)
    {
        _execute = execute;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter) => (_canExecute == null) ? true : _canExecute(parameter);

    public void Execute(object parameter) => _execute();
}
```

I found out through testing that I simply can't just do this:

```
public RelayCommand TestCommand;
```

I have to do this:

```
public RelayCommand TestCommand { get; set; }
```

Otherwise declaring the command in the constructor like this:

```
TestCommand = new RelayCommand(TestCommandFunction);

public void TestCommandFunction(){}
```

won't work. Why is this the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Binding generally doesn't work to fields. Most binding is based on the *ComponentModel* *PropertyDescriptor* model, which works on properties. This enables notifications, validation, and none of which works with fields.

So yes you need properties.

You can either initialise them in your constructor or a common pattern is using a lazy loading style syntax with a backing field and an expression bodied property

```
private RelayCommand _testCommand;

public RelayCommand TestCommand => _testCommand ?? (_testCommand = new RelayCommand(...));
```

Comment: Ahh that makes a lot of sense. Thanks!